# MVC DropdownList with complex types

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

First of all: Yes I've read up on similar threads on StackOverflow, but just can't it get to work properly. I've tried many options and feel like I'm really close to the solution but I guess I just need that last extra helping hand.

So I'm working on an MVC app related to Formula 1 and busy with a form to edit a driver profile. A driver has 2 complex types being Country and Team.
What I want is a dropdownlist showing each Country (or Team) as one simple line of text.

Basicly my issue is passing on my list of SelectItems into the view.
Hard coding selectionitems into the dropdownlist would be no issue, but that's not possible in my case.

[Controller Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osfl8.jpg)
This seems rather straight forward to me.

I am using the [UIHint] annotation to refer to an EditorTemplate.

[EditDriver viewmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XBBt.jpg)

In the "EditDriver" VIEW only the following code is relevant:

```
@Html.LabelFor(d => d.Country);
@Html.EditorFor(d => d.Country, new { SelectItemsCountry = Model.SelectItemsCountry });
```

[EditorTemplate CountryDropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoTl4.jpg)

with it's viewmodel:

```
public class EditCountryVM
{
    public Country DriverCountry { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectItemsCountry { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the following runtime error:

{"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Country_6DD4DB52DA6163390B9DC52D80C4EE400184AA68D9D1FF3BC7C013D6725EDDB0', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'WebApp_Formula1_2018.Models.EditCountryVM'."}

To me it seemed like the extra object parameter in Html.Editorfor would merge this data in my viewmodel, but this is clearly not the case?

Appreciate your help!
Cheers
Kevin

Comment: Please post any code as formatted code in your question, not as an image. Also, format your error using a code block or other method.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code a bit and am getting closer to the solution.

My EditorTemplate "CountryDropdown.cshtml" now looks like this:

```
@using WebApp_Formula1_2018.Models;
@model Country
@Html.DropDownList("", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["SelectItemsCountry"])
```

Now my editing form is showing properly with the correct country being selected.
However after submitting I'm getting the following exception:
"System.ArgumentException: 'Value cannot be null or empty."

The viewData seems to have gotten lost in the process? Maybe this is not the right way to tackle this problem?

Comment: This is not the answer, and should be an edit to your question. But `Cvalueuntry` is a complex object and you cannot bind a `<select>` to a complex object (it binds to and post back a simple value - e.g. `int`, `string` etc)

Comment: And the error would occur if you return the view in the POST method and did not repopulate `SelectItemsCountry`